# Get 2 number in one For loop

Tags: python

How do I get two numbers in a loop?
I tried to use the `zip` function.

```py
matrix = [[0,1,1,2],[0,5,0,0],[2,0,3,3]]
print(len(matrix[0]))
print(range(len(matrix[0])))
for i, x in zip(range(len(matrix)), range(len(matrix[0]))):
    print(x)
```

But instead of my output being `0,1,2,3`, it only prints up to `2`

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix has only 3 indexes, so its range will produce `0, 1, 2`. `zip` will only zip objects up to the length of the shortest object. If you want to zip to the length of the longest then you should import `zip_longest` from the itertools module. It will then zip based on the longest list and produce `None` in place of the items in the shorter list.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
matrix = [[0,1,1,2],
[0,5,0,0],
[2,0,3,3]]
print(len(matrix[0]))
print(range(len(matrix[0])))
for i, x in zip_longest( range(len(matrix)) , range(len(matrix[0])) ):
    print(i, x)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3
range(0, 4)
0 0
1 1
2 2
None 3
```

However this seems very verbose and clunky, you might be better to state what your really trying to achieve as there may be a much cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I think he wants to do like an enumerate function. Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
matrix = [[0,1,1,2],
         [0,5,0,0],
         [2,0,3,3]]
for i in matrix:
    for i, x in enumerate(i):
        print(i, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need range for your given list.....
I am improving @Martin Schere answer based on your doubt....

```
matrix = [[0,1,1,2],
     [0,5,0,0],
     [2,0,3,3]]
for i,x in enumerate(matrix):
     print("range="+str(i))#0,1,2
     print("list="+str(x))#prints your matrix
```

hope...it will help you...